# PHP not being parsed after redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to create a login page for some sites that I manage. So far it worked easy enough by having a login page which connects to a database which told the page where to redirect them.

I also have an .htaccess that rewrites the URL to pass through an authorisation page that just checks if a session has been started then pushes them through.

The problem I have is that when an admin logs in to the admin page it isn't parsing the php and when I go 'view source' I can see all the code... how do I get it to parse the php?

#### .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../authorise.php?file=$1 [NC]
```

#### authorise.php

```
session_name('TSiteStats');  
session_start();  
if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']))  readfile ($_SESSION['redirect'] . '/' . $_REQUEST['file']);  
else header("Location: ../login.php");
```

Comment: Did you forget the opening <?php  ?

Comment: Well, for starters, make sure you're opening the `<?php` tags correctly?

Comment: Yes, that was the first thing I checked. All tags opened and closed properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure.

Does you file use the `<?php` and `?>` tags. These tag will tell Apache to load the PHP code to be executed.

Also, does the script can be executed (has the authorization to be executed by Apache).

Last thing, your code is using `readfile` which output the content of the file and not execute this one. Are you sure you want to readfile and not include it?

Comment: Do not forget to upvote and accept the question for future reference. Thank you have a nice day.